# How to pass input parameter to solr

Tags: postgresql, solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I have three input parameters in postgresql stored procedure I need to pass this input parameters in solr, input parameters are member_id, apps_name, photo_id.  In URL I need to get :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo7/select?q=*%3A*&fq=i_member_id+%3A+14194+AND+i_photo_id : 20140810832&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true
```

based on it I will display o/p parameters.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no spaces in the query syntax for a fq.

If you have documents with the value `14194` in a field named `i_member_id`, the proper `fq` is `fq=i_member_id:14194`. If both values will change independently, it's usually preferrable to cache each filter by itself instead of combining them. i.e.

```
fq=i_member_id:14194&fq=i_photo_id:20140810832
```

If it makes more sense to cache the result as a single query (i.e., the i_photo_id part will never be reused for other member_ids), the AND syntax you've used is correct:

```
fq=i_member_id:14194 AND i_photo_id:20140810832
```